# Eclipse dependency error while installing ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install ADT plugin in Eclipse Galileo 3.5.2 on my ubuntu 10.04. But I am getting the dependency error. Please help me to fix the error.

This is the error detail which I am getting.

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse Platform 3.5.2 (Eclipse Platform 3.5.2)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Core Runtime 3.7.0.v20110110 (org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.7.0.v20110110)
    Core Runtime 3.5.0.v20090525 (org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.5.0.v20090525)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.5.2 (Eclipse Platform 3.5.2)
    To: org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.5.0.v20090525]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685)
    To: org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.6.0
```

Comment: use the latest eclipse juno

Answer (score 2):

The ADT Plug-in page [states](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

```
Eclipse Helios (Version 3.6.2) or higher is required for ADT 21.1.0.
```

The output you posted shows you are using ADT 21.1.0, so, it seems like it might be time to update eclipse :)

Comment: thanks @JustDanyul for helping  For some reason my eclipse is not updating to 3.6 from 3.5 . So I have downloaded  Juno Service Release 2 and it worked fine for me http://eclipse.org/mobile/

Answer (score 1):

Do not bother anymore with eclipse 3.x

Download the latest Eclipse (Juno - 4.2) : http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

OR event better if you do only android development, download the android developer package which has its built-in eclipse version with ADT pre-installed : http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also download org.eclipse.core.runtime-3.7.0.v20110110.jar in:http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgeclipsecoreruntime370v20110110jar.htm